# Excel macro for not proportional gradient colors assigned to a range of cells

Tags: excel, colors, gradient, vba

I need to write a macro such that: I fill in A1 with a purple color. Then as I run the macro, A2 should be a little lighter, A3 even lighter... etc until A20 is white. But this color change **should not** be proportional, i.e. the marginal color change in cells "becoming ligher" should be falling (such that A2 is to a larger degree ligher than A1, than A3 ligher than A2). **The bottomline is: cells should become ligher but not proportionately.**

[image]

So far I have the following code:

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim firstCell As Range 'the first cell, and the cell whose color will be used for all others.
Dim cellColor As Long 'the cell color that you will use, based on firstCell
Dim allCells As Range 'all cells in the column you want to color
Dim c As Long  'cell counter
Dim tintFactor As Double 'computed factor based on # of cells.
Dim contrast As Integer

Set firstCell = Range("A1")
cellColor = firstCell.Interior.Color
contrast = Range("F5").Value


Set allCells = Range("A1:A20")

For c = allCells.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    allCells(c).Interior.Color = cellColor
    allCells(c).Interior.TintAndShade = contrast * _
        (c - 1) / allCells.Cells.Count
  Next

End Sub
```

I tried to introduce an integer varialbe `Dim contrast as Integer` to cell "F5", so that as I change the value in "F5", the marginal decrease in color would fall. But this does not work. How can I improve the code?

Comment: that was most kind of you, thank you. good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below goes code with `tan` function which result with the following picture:

[image]

In column B you find difference between T&S color parameter.

```
Sub Macro3_proposal()

Dim firstCell As Range 'the first cell, and the cell whose color will be used for all others.
Dim cellColor As Long 'the cell color that you will use, based on firstCell
Dim allCells As Range 'all cells in the column you want to color
Dim c As Long  'cell counter
Dim tintFactor As Double 'computed factor based on # of cells.
Dim contrast As Integer

Set firstCell = Range("A1")
cellColor = firstCell.Interior.Color
contrast = Range("F5").Value


Set allCells = Range("A1:A20")

Dim allCellsCount!
allCellsCount = allCells.Cells.Count - 1
For c = 1 To allCellsCount 
    allCells(c + 1).Interior.Color = cellColor

    allCells(c + 1).Value = contrast * (Tan(c / allCellsCount) / Tan(1))
    allCells(c + 1).Interior.TintAndShade = contrast * (Tan(c / allCellsCount) / Tan(1))
  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a data validation on cell F5 that its content should be between -1 and 1 then change your code such that the contrast isnt an Integer, but a Double (floating point):

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim firstCell As Range 'the first cell, and the cell whose color will be used for all others.
    Dim cellColor As Long 'the cell color that you will use, based on firstCell
    Dim allCells As Range 'all cells in the column you want to color
    Dim c As Long  'cell counter
    Dim tintFactor As Double 'computed factor based on # of cells.
    Dim contrast As Double 'double precision factor for changing the contrast 0= none higher is more

    Set firstCell = Range("A1")
    cellColor = firstCell.Interior.Color
    contrast = Range("F5").Value


    Set allCells = Range("A1:A20")

    For c = allCells.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        allCells(c).Interior.Color = cellColor
        allCells(c).Interior.TintAndShade = _
            contrast * (c - 1) / (allCells.Cells.Count -1)

    Next

End Sub
```

A value of 0 is all the same color, up to 1 will increase into more white in the bottom, decreasing to -1 will add blackness to the bottom. The value cannot go further than -1 or 1 so those are your Cell F5 limits.

Next to auto update your nice ribbon of colors add a `Worksheet_Change` sub to your VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F5")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Macro3
    End If
End Sub
```

All set!

Comment: Thank you. But this does not fully solve the problem. When I change values in "F5" (e.g. from 1 to 0.7), what happens is that ALL of those 20 cells ("A1:A20") become EQUALLY darker. And the last cell A20 is not white anymore. However, I need my fist cell "A1" to be purple and the last cell "A20" to be white no matter what... And, the distribution of color for the cells in between (i.e. A2:A19) should NOT be proportional. If this equation makes sense I mean that the colors should be: `(A1-A2)>(A2-A3)>(A3-A4)>(A4-A5)>....>(A18-A19)>(A19-A20);`

Comment: i.e. the degree to which A2 is "whiter" than A1 should be MORE than the degree to which A3 is "whiter" than A2.

Comment: when i run it it works perfectly fine. Have you actually changed the code into what I posted, if not please do that first? Also if you want it disproportionally you should precisely define what you want, if you get stuck with that please post a NEW question with that concern (otherwise 1 question becomes a never ending one, helping no one in the community for clear reference)

Comment: If you want the final cell to be really really white change the TintAndShade  into `contrast * (c - 1) / (allCells.Cells.Count-1)` so you get 19 intervals between full color and completely white, thus 20 colors in total!  I changed the script in my answer accordingly

Comment: for the "disproportionate" part, please be aware I am not unwilling to help, but there are infinite trajectories for this path (exponential, quadratic, circular, sinus, cosinus, tanges, discrete rules, combination of these, even others).

Comment: thanks, actually I changed the code as you suggested. I needed any of (exponential or any other) trends. I just have difficulty modifying `allCells(c).Interior.TintAndShade = _
            contrast * (c - 1) / (allCells.Cells.Count -1)` What can I do? Should I ask it as a different question?